# Check if element exists in the database

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson, database

I have a collection in MongoDB organised like the following:

```
{
    "_id"      : ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "Username" : username
    "Password" : encrypted_password
    "Position" : position
    .....
}
{
    "_id"      : ObjectId("yyyyyy"),
    "Username" : username2
    "Password" : encrypted_password2
    "Position" : position2
    .....
}
```

I want to iterate through the collection and check if a username+password combination exists but I can't seem to figure it out :/

I'm using the MongoDB Driver with C# and this is what I have so far:

```
    public bool DoesSaveDataExist(String database, String collection, string username, string password)
    {
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient(); // connect to localhost
        MongoServer server = client.GetServer();
        MongoDatabase test = server.GetDatabase(database);

        var GetFromCollection = test.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);

        byte[] passwordToByte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        passwordToByte = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(passwordToByte);
        String hash = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(passwordToByte);

        IMongoQuery query = new QueryDocument {
            { "Player Name", username },
            { "Password", hash}
        };

        return false;
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: SHA is too fast to store passwords.  You need to use a salted, iterated hash.  Use PBKDFv2.  Also, hashes are not ASCII; use base63 or store a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

You use "Username" in the DB and "Player Name" in the query... this is why you don't match any documents in the MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return GetFromCollection.Find(Query.And(Query.EQ("Username", username), Query.EQ("Password", hash))).Any();
```

You probably need a 'using System.Linq;' reference for this to compile.
This should return true if any matches were found.

Comment: Thank you! How would I then edit the specific subsequent entries after that match? For example, the 'position' found after that username? :S I can call Update.Set("Position", "New Position"); but not sure how to on the specific user...

Comment: If you didn't call the Any method at the end, the call would return the collection of users with the given name and password (probably a single user at the most), so you can just do that, and return that instead.

Comment: I'm trying that but it's not entering my foreach loop doing it that way :S Unless I'm understanding the cursors wrong? var GetFromCollection = test.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);

            var query = GetFromCollection.Find(Query.And(Query.EQ("Username", username),Query.EQ("Password", hash)));

            foreach (var q in query)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(q.ToString());
            }